# Vectorized search of element indeces

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two integer numpy arrays, let's say, `arr1` and `arr2`, that are permutations of `range(some_length)`

I want to get the third one, where

`arr3[idx] = arr1.get_index_of(arr2[idx])` for all `idx = 0,1,2,..., some_length-1`

here `get_index_of method` is a pseudo-method of getting index of some element in the collection.

That can be done with naive looping through all the indeces, searching correspondnent element with subsequent assignment of it's index, etc.

But that is slow -- O(n^2). Can it be done faster (At least n*log(n) complexity)? Can it be done via pretty numpy methods? Maybe some sorting with non-trivial `key=` parameter? Sure there is some elegant solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/array_object.html#fancy-indexing and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

say, `a` is a *permutation* of `0..9`:

```
>>> a = np.random.permutation(10)
>>> a
array([3, 7, 1, 8, 2, 4, 6, 0, 9, 5])
```

then, the *indexer* array is:

```
>>> i = np.empty(len(a), dtype='i8')
>>> i[a] = np.arange(len(a))
>>> i
array([7, 2, 4, 0, 5, 9, 6, 1, 3, 8])
```

this means that, index of say `0` in `a` is `i[0] == 7`, which is true since `a[7] == 0`.

So, in your example, say if you have an extra vector `b`, you can do as in below:

```
>>> b
array([5, 9, 4, 8, 6, 1, 7, 2, 3, 0])
>>> i[b]
array([9, 8, 5, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4, 0, 7])
```

which means that, say, `b[0] == 5` and index of `5` in `a` is `i[b][0] == 9`, which is true, since `a[9] = 5 = b[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try a test case

```
In [166]: arr1=np.random.permutation(10)
In [167]: arr2=np.random.permutation(10)
In [168]: arr1
Out[168]: array([4, 3, 2, 9, 7, 8, 5, 1, 6, 0])
In [169]: arr2
Out[169]: array([9, 2, 6, 4, 0, 3, 1, 7, 8, 5])
```

`np.where(arr1==i)` performs your `get_index_of method`, so your iterative solution is:

```
In [170]: np.array([np.where(arr1==i)[0] for i in arr2]).flatten()
Out[170]: array([3, 2, 8, 0, 9, 1, 7, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)
```

A vectorized approach is to do an 'outter' comparison between the 2 arrays.  This produces a `(10,10)` array, to which we can apply `where` to get the indices.  Still an O(n^2) method, but it is mostly compiled.  On this size of a problem it is 5x faster.

```
In [171]: np.where(arr1==arr2[:,None])
Out[171]: 
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32),
 array([3, 2, 8, 0, 9, 1, 7, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32))
```